# Shortest path in C

Tags: c, algorithm

## Main Structure

I have a BST where i extract some data with this structure:

```
struct Node
{
    int distance;
    int jumpRange;
    int visited; //I added this but don't know if it's a good idea
};

typedef struct Node *node;
```

with distance the position of the node and jumpRange how much can i travel from  this node(to reach another node).

My Data are like this: 
[image]

## Objective

My function is like this

```
int x = planTravel(root, 20, 50, &path);
```

with x the number of selected nodes, root is needed for extracting the data, 20 the starting distance, 50 the target and path the list of nodes of the shortest path.

```
int planTravel(node root, int start, int target, path *p)
{
    node *nodes = NULL;
    int count; //number of nodes in nodes
    nodes = find_nodes_where_value_inRange(root, start, target, target - start, &count); //array of nodes



    return 0;
}
```

I want the shortest path from the start node to another

## Example

[image]

In the example i have 2 shortest path 20-45-50 or 20-30-50, 20-30-45-50 it's not the shortest path and 20-50 can't work because 20 has only 25 of range and can't reach 50

In this example i should return the path 20-30-50 because it's required to return the path with the nodes closest to the start.[image]

## Additional problem

If possible i'd like to make the same code working even on the opposite, like from 50(start) to 20(target)( and sometimes it's not the same because of the jumpRange on start)

## My Idea

I was thinking to use Dijkstra or some kind of Dynamic Programming (but i suck at it).
What's the pseudocode to implement Dijkstra in a case like that?

Comment: This is related to, but not identical to, [Shortest path in a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899894/shortest-path-in-a-tree).

Comment: I think it's time for you to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mre] of your own attempt, or how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Added the question sorry

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. You seem to be aware of Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest paths. In this case a straightforward application of dijkstra's algorithm would work. Where exactly is the issue?

Comment: When I googled "dijkstra's algorithm pseudocode" I got 153,000 results.  Is there something in one of the resources you checked that you didn't understand?

Comment: @Cubic i don't have a graph, i only have an array of nodes, can i apply Dijkstra anyway? There are better way to solve this problem instead of Dijkstra? Dynamic programming is better in this case?

Comment: @StephenNewell the fact that they have a graph but i only have a list of nodes

Comment: On another note, please don't do `typedef struct Node *node;`. Type-aliases as pointers too often lead to confusion and problem in debugging and maintenance.

Comment: If your nodes are in an array, but you can visualize them as a graph, it doesn't matter.  I can think of two cases off memory where I've implemented Dijkstra's, and in both cases my input was an array.

Comment: @LucaPedersoli you have a graph here. You just don't have an in-memory representation of the edges, but you don't really need one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, i did this to avoid double pointer (they scare me)

Comment: Ok i try. Another question, there are better way to solve this problem or Dijsktra is the best one?

Comment: @LucaPedersoli I'd recommend trying to come up with _a_ solution before you worry about which one is "best".

Comment: Dijkstra = shortest path between two specific nodes. Prim = shortest way to include all nodes in the graph. Pick whatever applies.